# OS X - Cannot fork process

Tags: macos

Ever since the Dyn DNS attack last week (I know, seems unrelated, but began as soon as the attack began), my laptop has started acting up.

Whenever I have enough programs open, I start getting errors in my terminal saying that it `cannot fork process` for random programs like git, zsh, postgres, etc. Basically anything.

Whenever this happens, I also have issues in chrome and other apps. For example, in chrome, new tabs immediately crash upon opening.

I'm able to fix this issue by simply quitting a few programs. This would lead me to believe it's a memory or CPU usage issue, but whenever I check Activity Monitor when this happens, I have less than 20% CPU utilization and am nowhere near hitting swap memory.

Comment: Not all resources are visible in Activity Monitor. In fact, most aren't. You're probably running out of PIDs or something like that.

Comment: that was my hunch as well. how can I check that? I figured an issue like that would be solve by restarting the computer, but alas it was not

Comment: so I decided to monitor my PIDs while working until the error arose to see what was going on. 

i ran `while true; do ps a | grep ps | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs echo $(date); sleep 1; done`

when the issue resurfaced, i was at PID 32286. after quitting a few programs the issue disappeared, but the processes have continued climbing well above 32286.

Comment: Yeah, that was really just an example of a not-so-obviously limited resource. There are others like file descriptors and whatnot. Unfortunately, I’m not that familiar with Darwin/OS X internals, so I can’t provide further insight, sorry!